# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in php

Tags: php

I'm first in Stackoverflow, and sorry for my bad english, I'm going to improve.
I want to ask to you, I have some trouble when I displaying chart in my php.
here is error result :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (plugins.js:112)
at Function.each (jquery.js:374)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:139)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.plugins (plugins.js:109)
at Object.app.init (app.js:61)
at app.js:556
at app.js:560
```

here is error result error source from Inpect Element in Browser
[here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQiuE.png)

and here is my code :

```
echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";
      echo "<div class='widget'>";
        echo "<header class='widget-header'>";
        echo "<h4 class='widget-title'>Chart Final Association Rule</h4>";
        echo "</header>";
        echo "<hr class='widget-separator'>";
        echo "<div class='widget-body'>";
        echo "<div data-plugin='chart' style='height:300px' data-options='{
                tooltip : {
                  trigger: 'axis'
                },
                legend: {
                  data:['as']
                },
                calculable : true,
                  xAxis : [
                {
                type : 'category',
                  data : ['11']
                }
                ],
                yAxis : [
                {
                  type : 'value'
                }
                ],
                series : [
                {
                  name:'Sale',
                  type:'bar',
                  data:[2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3],
                  markPoint : {
                  data : [
                    {type : 'max', name: 'Max'},
                    {type : 'min', name: 'Min'}
                    ]
                  },
                  markLine : {
                    data : [
                      {type : 'average', name: 'Average'}
                    ]
                   }
                  },
                  {
                  name:'Market',
                  type:'bar',
                  data:[2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3],
                  markPoint : {
                  data : [
                    {name : 'Max', value : 182.2, xAxis: 7, yAxis: 183, symbolSize:18},
                    {name : 'Min', value : 2.3, xAxis: 11, yAxis: 3}
                  ]
                  },
                  markLine : {
                    data : [
                      {type : 'average', name : 'Average'}
                    ]
                   }
                  }
                 ]
                }'>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
```

I don't know how to fix it, somebody can tell me, please.
best regard

Comment: That's a Javascript error, not PHP. Show the JS code.

Comment: The large JSON structure inline with an HTML element looks like it would result in very invalid HTML.

Comment: When I create in Html file I'ts work, but in PHP didn't work

Comment: And why this does not work well, whereas my datatable function can work but for this one I am confused.

Comment: @MiyaAzhila: What "datatable function"?  This code "doesn't work" because it produces invalid HTML.  Separate your JavaScript from your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes (`'`) for your `data-options` value, but you are also using them for the keys in the JSON string inside. You could fix this by using double quotes for the attribute value instead, escaped (`\"`), because you're in the `echo` string. If this is not the main cause, it's at least a significant problem.

@Spectarion also brought my attention to the fact that your JSON-like string is not valid JSON, so you will likely run into problems, if you're going to parse it using a JSON parser. JSON requires double quotes and all keys must be quoted.

Comment: And also, keys without quotes are invalid.

Comment: @Spectarion But then again, the bigger problem is that the JSON standard does not permit single quotes at all.

Comment: Can you give me an example?
I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

```
echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";
    echo "<div class='widget'>";
        echo "<header class='widget-header'>";
            echo "<h4 class='widget-title'>Chart Final Association Rule</h4>";
        echo "</header>";
        echo "<hr class='widget-separator'>";
        echo "<div class='widget-body'>";
            echo "<div data-plugin='chart' style='height:300px' data-options='{\"tooltip\":{\"trigger\":\"axis\"},\"legend\":{\"data\":[\"as\"]},\"calculable\":true,\"xAxis\":[{\"type\":\"category\",\"data\":[\"11\"]}],\"yAxis\":[{\"type\":\"value\"}],\"series\":[{\"name\":\"Sale\",\"type\":\"bar\",\"data\":[2,4.9,7,23.2,25.6,76.7,135.6,162.2,32.6,20,6.4,3.3],\"markPoint\":{\"data\":[{\"type\":\"max\",\"name\":\"Max\"},{\"type\":\"min\",\"name\":\"Min\"}]},\"markLine\":{\"data\":[{\"type\":\"average\",\"name\":\"Average\"}]}},{\"name\":\"Market\",\"type\":\"bar\",\"data\":[2.6,5.9,9,26.4,28.7,70.7,175.6,182.2,48.7,18.8,6,2.3],\"markPoint\":{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"Max\",\"value\":182.2,\"xAxis\":7,\"yAxis\":183,\"symbolSize\":18},{\"name\":\"Min\",\"value\":2.3,\"xAxis\":11,\"yAxis\":3}]},\"markLine\":{\"data\":[{\"type\":\"average\",\"name\":\"Average\"}]}}]}'>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

**Second solution:**

```
?>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='widget'>
            <header class='widget-header'>
                <h4 class='widget-title'>Chart Final Association Rule</h4>
            </header>
            <hr class='widget-separator'>
            <div class='widget-body'>
                <div data-plugin='chart' style='height:300px' data-options='{\"tooltip\":{\"trigger\":\"axis\"},\"legend\":{\"data\":[\"as\"]},\"calculable\":true,\"xAxis\":[{\"type\":\"category\",\"data\":[\"11\"]}],\"yAxis\":[{\"type\":\"value\"}],\"series\":[{\"name\":\"Sale\",\"type\":\"bar\",\"data\":[2,4.9,7,23.2,25.6,76.7,135.6,162.2,32.6,20,6.4,3.3],\"markPoint\":{\"data\":[{\"type\":\"max\",\"name\":\"Max\"},{\"type\":\"min\",\"name\":\"Min\"}]},\"markLine\":{\"data\":[{\"type\":\"average\",\"name\":\"Average\"}]}},{\"name\":\"Market\",\"type\":\"bar\",\"data\":[2.6,5.9,9,26.4,28.7,70.7,175.6,182.2,48.7,18.8,6,2.3],\"markPoint\":{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"Max\",\"value\":182.2,\"xAxis\":7,\"yAxis\":183,\"symbolSize\":18},{\"name\":\"Min\",\"value\":2.3,\"xAxis\":11,\"yAxis\":3}]},\"markLine\":{\"data\":[{\"type\":\"average\",\"name\":\"Average\"}]}}]}'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
```

---

Problems fixed:

- Keys without quotes are not valid.
- Values wrapped in single quotes are not valid.